# Raycasting to intersect objects that have been displaced by vertex shader

Tags: three.js

Let's say I have a vertical list of meshes created from `PlaneBufferGeometry` with `ShaderMaterial`. The meshes are distributed vertically and evenly spaced.

The list will have two states:

1. Displaying the meshes as they are
2. Displaying meshes with each object's vertices transformed by the vertex shader to the same arbitrary value, let's say `z = -50`. This gives a zoomed out effect and the user can scroll through this list (in the code we do this by moving the camera `y` position)

In my app I'm trying to make my mouseover events work for the second state but it's tricky since the GPU transforms the vertices so the updated vertices are not reflected in the attributes on the JS side.

*Note I've looked into GPU picking and do not want to use it because I believe there should be a simpler way to do this without render targets

### Attempted Solution

My current approach is to manually change the `boundingBox` of each plane when we are in the second state like so:

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(plane);
box.min.z = -50;
box.max.z = -50;

plane.geometry.boundingBox = box;
```

And then to change the `boundingSphere`'s center to have the same `z` position of `-50` after computing it.

I did this approach because I looked into the `Raycaster` and `Mesh` code for THREE.js and it seems like they check both boundingSphere and boundingBox for object intersections. So I thought if I modified both of them to reflect the transforms done by the GPU, the raycaster would work fine but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

The relevant raycaster code is here:

```
// mouse being vec2 of normalized coordinates and camera being a perspective camera
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( planes );
```

### Possible Theories

The only thing I can think of that's wrong about this approach is maybe I'm not projecting the mouse coords right? Since all the objects now lie on the plane `z = -50` would I need to project those mouse coordinates to that plane?

Comment: Take a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/raycaster-intersection-with-morphtarget/3527?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks I saw that, seems to be a complex solution to calculate AABB. I think last resort I could use a separate box object to intersect from but my question is trying to understand how the raycaster works and if I could potentially "hack" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [the link](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/raycaster-intersection-with-morphtarget/3527?u=prisoner849) posted by @prisoner849 I found a working solution to just create additional transparent planes equal to the number of planes in the scene. In these planes, I set the `z` position to `-50` and just intersect with these when in state #2.

A bit hacky, but works for now.